# Where can i find interesting problems to solve?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, problem-solving

i would like to increase my problem solving skills in elementary math but i don't know where to start. Do you guys have any suggestion or recomendation? It can be of books, magazines, olympiad tests, sites, etc.

Thx

Comment: visit the side www.mathlinks.ro

Comment: Maybe a book of past math olympiad problems?

Answer (score 1):

Prealgebra - Mathcounts

Introduction to Algebra - Mathcounts

Introduction to Number Theory - Mathcounts

Introduction to Geometry - Mathcounts

Introduction to Counting & Probability - Mathcounts

All Books up to this point are located [**HERE**](https://artofproblemsolving.com/store). These books are composed of challenge problems which will prepare you for future math competitions.

[Holt McDougal Prealgebra](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0030934680)

[Algebra $1$ - Common Core Edition (McGraw Hill)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0076639231)

[Geometry Common Core](https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&q=Geometry%20Common%20Core&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAONgecTozS3w8sc9YSmnSWtOXmO04eIKzsgvd80rySypFNLjYoOyVLgEpXj10_UNDZPNTdJMDcxNNBik-LlQhXgAzADafVAAAAA&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjOj-ml5IzZAhWquFkKHTr5AWcQ6RMIdDAL&biw=1440&bih=710)

[Algebra $2$ - Common Core Edition (McGraw Hill)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0078952662)

Are some other books I would recommend. I am currently being taught Algebra $2$ in my school, and the book above provides pretty good insight about it.